# How to avoid the overflow while taking derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
m0 = 0.0055;
Gs = 10.08;
Gv[x_] := x*Gs;
M[s_] := m0 - Gs*s;
Ep[s_, p_] := (M[s]^2 + p^2)^(1/2)
mue[n_, mu_, x_] := mu - Gv[x]*n;

fn[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, 
x_?NumericQ] := -(6/\[Pi]^2) T NIntegrate[
p^2 (Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] - mue[n, mu, x])/T)]] + 
  Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] + mue[n, mu, x])/T)]]), {p, 
0, \[Infinity]}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]

dfndmu[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, 
x_?NumericQ] := D[fn[s, n, T, mud, x], mud] /. {mud -> mu}

dfndT[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, 
x_?NumericQ] := D[fn[s, n, Td, mu, x], Td] /. {Td -> T}

dfndmu[-0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]

dfndT[-0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]
```

I am trying to take the derivative with respect to T and mu. For all values of mu I can evaluate 'dfndmu' but for small values of T, I cannot evaluate 'dfndT'. It shows overflow problem. How can I cure it?

Comment: One possibility might be to work in higher precision.

Comment: Apparently, it does not help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate the integrand instead of differentiating the integral:

```
m0 = 0.0055;
Gs = 10.08;
Gv[x_] = x*Gs;
M[s_] = m0 - Gs*s;
Ep[s_, p_] = (M[s]^2 + p^2)^(1/2);
mue[n_, mu_, x_] = mu - Gv[x]*n;

fn[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, 
  x_?NumericQ] := -(6/\[Pi]^2) T NIntegrate[
  p^2 (Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] - mue[n, mu, x])/T)]] + 
  Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] + mue[n, mu, x])/T)]]), {p, 
  0, \[Infinity]}]

dfndmu[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, mu1_?NumericQ, 
  x_?NumericQ] := -(6/\[Pi]^2) T NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[D[p^2 (Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] - mue[n, mu, x])/T)]] + 
    Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] + mue[n, mu, x])/T)]]), mu] /. 
    mu -> mu1], {p, 0, \[Infinity]}]

dfndT[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, T1_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, 
  x_?NumericQ] := -(6/\[Pi]^2) NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[
    D[T p^2 (Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] - mue[n, mu, x])/T)]] + 
    Log[1 + Exp[-((Ep[s, p] + mue[n, mu, x])/T)]]), T] /. 
    T -> T1], {p, 0, \[Infinity]}]

dfndmu[-0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]
```

> 4.98657*10^-6

```
dfndT[-0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]
```

> -0.00381753

Comment: This certainly works. I was just wandering what is happening here!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation numerical differentiation is a terrible beast that is best left untouched. Very prone to noise and instability.